# How should I define a concrete object name in vue components

Tags: vue.js

```js
      Vue.component("blog-post", {
        props: ["post"],
        template: `
                  <div>
                  <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3> 
                  <p> #####: {{ post.content }} </p>
                  </div>
                  `
      });

      new Vue({
        el: "#blog-post-demo",
        data: {
          posts: [
            { id: 1, title: "My journey with Vue" },
            { id: 2, title: "Blogging with Vue" },
            { id: 3, title: "Why Vue is so fun" }
          ]
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="blog-post-demo" class="demo">
      <blog-post
        v-for="post in posts"
        v-bind:key="post.id"
        v-bind:title="post.title"
        v-bind:content="post.id"
      ></blog-post>
    </div>
```

The above example is not working. But I am able to make the below one work.

```js
      Vue.component("blog-post", {
        props: ["content", "title"],
        template: `
                  <div>
                  <h3>{{ title }}</h3> 
                  <p> #####: {{ content }} </p>
                  </div>
                  `
      });

      new Vue({
        el: "#blog-post-demo",
        data: {
          posts: [
            { id: 1, title: "My journey with Vue" },
            { id: 2, title: "Blogging with Vue" },
            { id: 3, title: "Why Vue is so fun" }
          ]
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="blog-post-demo" class="demo">
      <blog-post
        v-for="post in posts"
        v-bind:key="post.id"
        v-bind:title="post.title"
        v-bind:content="post.id"
      ></blog-post>
    </div>
```

Could someone explain what am I missing here?

Comment: First one props is `post` so it is not working while second one is `content` and `title` so it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, your component accept `post` as the prop, which is what you should pass from the parent component.

```js
      Vue.component("blog-post", {
        props: ["post"],
        template: `
                  <div>
                  <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3> 
                  <p> #####: {{ post.content }} </p>
                  </div>
                  `
      });

      new Vue({
        el: "#blog-post-demo",
        data: {
          posts: [
            { id: 1, title: "My journey with Vue" },
            { id: 2, title: "Blogging with Vue" },
            { id: 3, title: "Why Vue is so fun" }
          ]
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="blog-post-demo" class="demo">
      <blog-post
        v-for="post in posts"
        v-bind:post="post"
        v-bind:key="post.id"
      ></blog-post>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am confused because of this [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)